# PHP/mySQL - Select WHERE multiple values in an associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

```
$skuArray = array(00240=>123,00241=>456);
$getSkus = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM data WHERE sku IN($skuArray)");
```

My above code doesn't work, how can I make it SELECT all sku's FROM data WHERE sku = any of the key names in $skuArray? (00240 and 00241 in this case)

Hope this makes sense, Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$skuArray = array('00240'=>123, '00241'=>456);

$inSkus = array();

foreach (array_keys($skuArray) as $key)
{
    $inSkus[] = '"' . $key . '"';
}

$sql = 'SELECT sku FROM data WHERE sku IN (' . implode(', ', $inSkus) . ')';

echo $sql;
```

You need to have the keys as strings and you then need to wrap them in parentheses for the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

```
$skuArray = array('00240'=>123,'00241'=>456);
$keys = array_keys($skuArray);
$getSkus = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM data WHERE sku IN('" . join("','", $keys) . "')");
```

Comment: What's not working? Are the array keys wrapped in quotes, otherwise PHP reads them as octals. Is $skuArray NULL? In that case you'll get an error on line 2. You should probably check that $skuArray is not empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach($skuArray  as $value=>$key){
    if($where=="")
       $where= $value" = '".$key."'";
    else
       $where.= $value" = '".$key."'";
 }
 $getSkus = mysql_query("SELECT sku FROM data " .($where)?" WHERE   $where )":"");
```